# How to add control algorithm in ROS

Tags: control, ros, arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get values from an analog sensor via rosserial and I want to add an if condition to glow the LED if the sensor reading exceeds the threshold value. How can I add the if condition in ROS to accomplish this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201292/how-to-add-control-algorithm-in-ros/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2015-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a programming question. Will you be using C++ or Python? You'll need to create a ROS Node and subscribe to the rosserial topic in it and assign the values from there. Then, on the node's callback from the topic subscription you can add an if statement that checks if the threshold is met. When the threshold is met, you can send a command down rosserial to your analog sensor make the LED glow.

See: creating a ROS node http://wiki.ros.org/ROSNodeTutorialC%2B%2B
See: rosserial tutorials http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Tutorials
See: ROS subscribers and publishers http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

The function calls needed to accomplish your task can be found if you go through those tutorials. It shouldn't take long.

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0